# Delete Folders Based Upon A List Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, directory

I have a list of folders that I would like to delete.  How would I go about doing this in powershell?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Can you post what you've tried and hasn't worked?

Comment: I think most people that have some knowledge of powershell have a reasonable answer to your question but are loathed to provide you an answer as the purpose of the site is not to write your code for you but to assist you when you get stuck while coding something.  I'll give you a place to start though.  I would likely store the list in a csv file, import the csv and loop through the list applying the remove-item command to each.

Answer (score 0):

assumed you stored the folders in an powershell array like:

```
$foldersToDelete = @(
'c:\tmp\trashfolder1',
'c:\tmp\trashfolder2',
'c:\tmp\trashfolder3'
)
```

you can pipe the array to Remove-Item command:

```
$foldersToDelete | Remove-Item
```